# Изображение на весь экран и сохранение его пропорций при масштабировании

Tags: html, css

Посмотрите на эти два примера. Каким образом можно добиться, чтобы при изменении масштаба изображение оставалось таким же, каким и есть, без изменений. И это не похоже на cover, т.к. немного ниже и пункты, и меню, и контент, изображение же не полностью на весь сайт. Уже много гуглил, но врубиться в это никак не могу.
[Первый сайт](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_58273/), [второй сайт](http://www.templatemonster.com/ru/demo/58733.html).

Comment: На обоих сайтах используется `background-size: cover`. Приведите свой код, чтоб можно было рассмотреть вашу проблему.

Comment: background-size: cover растягивает изображение на всю страницу. А нужно растянуть её только в пределах одной области, ведь ниже все содержимое сайта.

Comment: это же основы вёрстки - ваш на htmlbook.ru , поучится бы вам

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации такого функционала используются относительные единицы измерения [vh](https://webref.ru/css/value/size) и свойство [`background-size`](https://webref.ru/css/background-size) со значением `cover`.

> `vh` - 1% от высоты области просмотра

> `cover` - Масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций так, чтобы его ширина или высота равнялась ширине или высоте блока.

Вот пример с использованием двух этих свойств:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.background {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://satyr.io/1920x1080/3') 50% 50%/cover no-repeat #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<p>Какое-то важное содержимое страницы</p>
```